# Dynamic import/load of local images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with a local JSON that has the following structure:

```
{
    "Data": [{
            "image": "../Images/project1.png",
        }, {
            "image": "../Images/project2.png",
        },
        {
            "image": ".../Images/project3.png",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am mapping this JSON into my component. I want it to show each image from the JSON. This is my component simplified:

```
import data from '../Data/Projects.json'

function ProjectsMenu(props){
    return(
        {data.Data.map(s =>{
            return(
                <img src={s["image"]} alt={s["image"]}></img>
            )
       })}  
}
```

This code doesn't load the images into the website. If I manually import the images it does work:

```
import Img from '../Images/present.png'
...
<img src={Img} alt={s["image"]}></img>
```

I want to be able to import them dynamially so that if the JSON is modified, I don't have to go back and add the image import to the code.

Comment: your code has an imbalance of `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter if yow pics are at Facebook, google or local host; it. Is a client/server architecture that uses the same protocol tcp/ip.

So as your are using cra the folder of yow pics need to be inside of your public folder, next to your index.html is

To fetch the images
`<img src=“/images/image-name.png” />`

Comment: That worked. I had located the images in a file inside /src/ and when I moved them to the public folder I could access them.

Answer (score 2):

```js
import data from '../Data/Projects.json'

function ProjectsMenu(props){
    return(
        {data.Data.map(s =>{
            return(
                <img src={require(s["image"])} alt={s["image"]}></img>
            )
       })}  
}
```

When we use dynamically then `s["image"]` will not load the image, we need to load the image  manually by `require(s["image"])`.

If it did't work then try `import(s["image"])`.

Comment: Import and require didn't work. The error was the following: Error: Cannot find module '../Images/project1.png'. I tried using it with .js files and it does import those correctly, but with images it doesn't. I solved the problem with Ernesto's answer

Comment: make sure to provide correct relative path.

Comment: Are you sure `s["image"]` is correct path.